# PostgreSQL find blank rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to search for non null values from the 'currentsheet' which works fine but some fields are actually blank rather than null. How can I find blank fields using postgreSQL as the below has not worked and still displays blank values under the 'currentsheet' field.

```
SELECT *
    FROM   PUBLIC._http_requests
    WHERE  (_http_requests.currentsheet IS NOT NULL OR _http_requests.currentsheet <> '')
           AND _http_requests.session_id IS NOT NULL
           AND _http_requests.http_referer IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AND` to check `_http_requests.currentsheet`. If it was `NULL`, then it would always be true for the `<> ''` check and vice versa.

As a way simpler example, you can use select statements without a table to help debug this sort of thing (from `psql` or whatever SQL query tool you like):

```
select (''   is not null or ''   <> '') as empty_result,
       (null is not null or null <> '') as null_result;

 empty_result | null_result 
--------------+-------------
 t            |
```

If the string is `''`, you get `true`. If the string is `null`, you get `null` (this is because comparisons with `null` are SQL oddities -- `select null = null;` results in `null`). Let's see what happens when we replace `or` with `and`:

```
select (''   is not null and ''   <> '') as empty_result,
       (null is not null and null <> '') as null_result;

 empty_result | null_result 
--------------+-------------
 f            | f
```

Neat! With `X is not null and X <> ''`, we get `false` when `X` is either `''` or `null`.

So the way to phrase the select statement to do what you actually want is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PUBLIC._http_requests
  WHERE _http_requests.currentsheet IS NOT NULL
    AND _http_requests.currentsheet <> ''
    AND _http_requests.session_id IS NOT NULL
    AND _http_requests.http_referer IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `AND _http_requests.currentsheet <> ''`. The AND is important there so that we exclude both.